# Stratio Sqoop complains of missing hadoop library

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2, stratio

I have pulled stratio sqoop docker containers as documented here:

https://stratio.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SQOOP0X2/Example+mysql+to+kafka

but when start the process of creating link between mysql and kafka. The step

"create link -c generic-jdbc-connector"

complains of missing hadoop library.

Is there something else pre-req for this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had missed a step of connecting sqoop client to sqoop server and got confused with the error message.